# Have link in frame change URL of entire window

Tags: html

Ok, first off, I didn't program this page with frames! I'll be getting rid of them later. For now I need to solve this problem.

There's a link within a frame. Instead of that link just changing the contents of the frame, I need it to change the URL of the entire window. How can I do this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: who downvoted this and why?  I think is a valid question... may be wrong formulated though!

Comment: I don't think this is possible,  the iframe and the window run in different secuirty contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the predefined [frame name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.16).

```
target="_top"
```